# Simple calculator should take 2 seconds to fix its like 10 lines

Tags: c++, calculator

Trying to make a simple Calculator but I can't even get my first function to work. I've been trying to be as organized as I can with my headers and .cpps because I remember back in the day those were important. Haha. I'm under the impression the header file is included in the main.cpp and it has the header guards. These are just declarations for my functions correct? And then Calculation'sFunctions.cpp is where I write the code for the previous declaration function I made on my header file. I'm also not sure when to include iostream and stdafx.h and all that etc. Anyway thanks in advance for your help guys, here is my 3 files all I'm trying at this point is to get an integer from the user.

```
Calculator.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "CalculatorDeclarations.h"
int main()
{
    int getFirstInteger(int userInput)
    return 0;
}

CalculatorDeclarations.h
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int getFirstInteger();
#endif

CalculationsFunctions.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int getFirstInteger(int userInput)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the first integer you would like to use." <<     std::endl;
    std::cin >> userInput;
    return userInput;
```

}

Errors:

```
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) ConsoleApplication1 c:\Users\Shane\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) ‌​1

Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe 1
```

Comment: What is the specific problem? Compilation error? Linker error? Unexpected behaviour? Segfaults?

Comment: Please describe any errors or output.  Is it a compile error?  Is it executing but not doing what you think it should?

Comment: Sorry durr, 2 errors:

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) ConsoleApplication1 c:\Users\Shane\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) 1

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe 1

Comment: Check out this line in the main function `int getFirstInteger(int userInput)`? Is this correct???

Comment: You should include both the program and any errors or unexpected output in the question.

Comment: Cool I did some editing and get no error now. But unfortunately it just displays the DOS menu saying press any key to continue instead of asking for an integer. Thanks for the fast replies guys. Are my headers and .cpp's setup correctly also?

Comment: @CroCro I've been messing with that for a while now and can't figure what the deal is. I'm self teaching myself C++. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well your first problem is your 'main' method

```
int main()
{
    int getFirstInteger(int userInput)
    return 0;
}
```

The syntax is incorrect (should be lined ended with a semi-colon). And you should be passing an int. So it could be modified to this

```
int main()
{
    int j = 1;
    getFirstInteger(j)
    return 0;
}
```

But it's worth looking at the implementation here. You're getting the user input within that method, so no need to pass in anything. And you're not using the output, so no need to return anything.

Also you've double included `#include<iostream>` This won't be a big issue in a small program but it's a waste and bad practice. Only include this where it's needed (which is in CalculationsFunctions.cpp). Don't think you need `#include "stdafx.h"` at all.